# Compare list of strings with specific key values in a properties file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, internationalization, resourcebundle

My scenario here Is to check strings are localized or not using Selenium automation with java, I have Properties file A with “Key and Value (xpaths)” and Properties_en file B (ResourceBundle), here is where I have the translated strings with “Key and Value(Strings)”.

I have used Properties file A and read the list of strings in web UI into an ArrayList function.

**List of strings**

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Phone

Now I want to compare that list of strings with specific Key "eg:LIST_" and its Value (strings) on Properties_en file B.

**Properties_en  file B (ResourceBundle)**

1. LIST_FIRST_NAME= First Name
2. LIST_LAST_NAME= Last Name
3. LIST_PHONE= Phone

Here i need to compare the list of strings with all Properties_en.properties key that contains "LIST_" and verify that the list of string are all present on the Properties_en file too.

Is there an way to achieve this ?

Comment: Actually your question is not clear, is list contains key value pair?? is this possible??...please explain more about your question..

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on [ask]. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried reduced to a [mcve], and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring to take only the desired string from the ArrayList.
You know that from List A the first element is First Name. Now, from List you know that the first element is LIST_First_Name. In order to compare them you need to make a substring for the first element in List B

```
List[0].substring(5)
```

and it will return the remaining string after eliminating the first 6 characters, which is First Name.
I hope this is what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read your resource bundle file and store its keys in a set. When reading file you need to split each string on '=' and store only the first part: set.add(line.split('=')[0]). This set will contain  then {LIST_FIRST_NAME, LIST_LAST_NAME, ...}.

Then you should read your first file, and for each field you need to test if it exists in a set. But first, you need convert this string to format LIST_FIELD_NAME_UPPERCASE_WITH_DASHES (note, this matches format of keys in ResourceBundle file)

If it the set contains this field, then this field was localized.

Outline is like this:

```
private Set<String> constructSet(Reader r) {
    String line;
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>()
    while(null != (line = reader.readLine())
    {
        String[] keyValue = line.split('=');
        if (null != keyValue[1])
            result.add(keyValue[0]);
    }

    return result;
}

public boolean test(Reader fileWithStringsReader, Reader resourceBundleReader)
{
    String line;
    Set<String> localizedKeys = constructSet(resourceBundleReader);
    while (null != (line = fileWithStringsReader.readLine()) 
    {
         if (!localizedKeys.contains(transformLine(line))
              return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private String transformLine(String line)
{
    if (null == line)
        return line;

    String[] splitLine = line.split(' ');
    return "LIST_" + StringUtils.join(splitLine, "_").toUpperCase();
}
```